# Ruby splits text into matrix creating a hash of counts of column 2

Tags: ruby

My code has two main concerns

- it seems unecessairly long
- unable to use new each_with_object method without shadowing answer(variable)

How should I proceed to reduce my code and make my intention clearer?

```
require 'pp'

data = <<EOF
0       303567       3584       Write       0.000000
1       55590       3072       Write       0.000000
0       303574       3584       Write       0.026214
1       240840       3072       Write       0.026214
1       55596       3072       Read       0.078643
0       303581       3584       Write       0.117964
1       55596       3072       Write       0.117964
0       303588       3584       Write       0.530841
1       55596       3072       Write       0.530841
0       303595       3584       Write       0.550502
1       240840       3072       Write       0.550502
1       55602       3072       Read       0.602931
0       303602       3584       Write       0.648806
1       55602       3072       Write       0.648806
0       303609       3584       Write       0.910950
1       55602       3072       Write       0.910950
0       303616       3584       Write       0.930611
1       240840       3072       Write       0.930611
1       55608       3072       Read       0.983040
0       303623       3584       Write       1.028915
1       55608       3072       Write       1.028915
0       303630       3584       Write       1.330380
1       55608       3072       Write       1.33038
EOF

ary = Array.new

data.each_line { |line|
  ary.push(line.split(" "))
}

answers = ary.map {|row| row[1]}

counts = Hash.new 0

answers.each do |answer|
  counts[answer] += 1
end

# creates shadowing
# solution = answer.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |answer,counts| counts[answer] += 1}
pp counts
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I didn't get your question on the shadowing part... Anyway, if you want to shorten it (and try to use something similar to each_with_object), you can do it this way, as a oneliner :)

```
pp data.each_line.with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|row,solution| solution[row.split(" ")[1]]+=1}
```

Except for the indirect handling with the double square brackets, I think that it is quite readable :)

Explanation (slightly changed by introducing an "index" temp variable for the sake of clarity)

```
pp data
 .each_line                                  #cycling line by line
 .with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |row,solution|  #using a Hash as accumulator, later called solution
     index=row.split(" ")[1]                 #setting the temp variable as the second column
     solution[index]+=1                      #increase the relevant counter in accumulator
 }
```